# RubyMine 7 Remote Debug No such file or directory error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, remote-debugging, rubymine

I am trying to debug a rails app that is on a vagrant machine using RubyMine. I setup remote ruby sdk via settings. I installed necessary gems for debugging (ruby-debug-base, ruby-debug-ide). When it tries to start debugger it gives the following output on debugger console:

```
/<remote_path_to_ruby>/bin/ruby -e 'at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)' /<remote_path>/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.29/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 33401 --dispatcher-port 52861 -- /<local_path>/railsapp/script/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
    bash: line 0: cd: /<local_path>/railsapp: No such file or directory
    /<local_path>/railsapp/Gemfile not found
```

is the path from vagrant machine,
and  is my host machine. It has the railsapp directory and Gemfile inside.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. 
You need to add a mapping for your **local project root -> remote project root**. You can add that in debug configurations. 
It solved problem for me.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can provide an example.

Comment: It is under Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment. Select the Remote Interpreter Host and click on the Mappings tab.

Comment: Same for WSL. If rubymine is installed in AppData, mapping c:\Users to /mnt/c/Users solves the problem as it allows rubymine to give to WSL the correct linux path to rdebug-ide.

Comment: That setting does not exist for me as described.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with WSL2 in RubyMine 2020. The accepted answer above pointed me in the right direction. I also use **rbenv** within WSL.

In the current versions of RubyMine there's no "Remote interpreter host" config (at least not for WSL), so I had to define "Project Path Mappings" in "Ruby SDK and Gems" section, for my ruby interpreter, by clicking on that folder icon:

[image: screenshot]

I specified mapping like this (replace `username` with your own user folder, and replace `Ubuntu-20.04` with your distro):

```
Local Path
//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/username

Remote Path
/home/username
```

This worked because both `.rbenv` and my project directory are there in my `home/username` folder. Otherwise I'd have to specify additional mappings for the project and `.rbenv`.

Not sure why it didn't work out of the box, without this manual mapping. Maybe I messed some configurations in my project earlier, and it would work with a fresh version. Anyway, this solved the problem for me, and hopefully will help others who search by the same error text.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for this! I spent the last day trying to understand why Rubocop was failing. You literally saved me!